# Pascal: Reading a text file with multiple lines

Tags: algorithm, pascal

I'm a first year in Computer Science and am struggling with a basic program...

I have an input file:

`aa bb cc dd`

The program:

```pascal
program readingas;
var df:text; i,j,k,x,wc:integer; A,B,C:array[1..255]of string; IPavad:string;
begin
assign(df,'duom.txt');reset(df);
wc:=1;
k:=1;
while not eof(df) do
    begin
        readln(df,A[wc]);
        wc:=wc+1;
    end;
    for i:=1 to wc-1 do
        begin
            for j:=1 to length(A[i]) do
                    if A[i][j]=' ' then k:=k+1 else B[k]:=B[k]+A[i][j];
                end;
close(df);
 for x:=1 to k do
    begin
        writeln(B[x]);
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

And the output file looks like this:

```
aa
bbccdd
```

when I want it to be :

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

How can I output each pair of characters at a time?

Comment: The line `if A[i][j]=' ' then k:=k+1 else B[k]:=B[k]+A[i][j];` and the surrounding loop is confusing.  In plain English, what are you trying to do with that part of the code?

Comment: If a line consists of more than a single word to split the line into words so I could output them with a Writeln(B[x]); into separate lines.

Comment: Try adding some writeln statements to your program so that you can see the variables in your program as it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
       B[k]:=B[k]+A[i][j];
```

is a concatenation that concatenates all texts together if there are no lines with texts containing a space inbetween. Those lines are skipped.

So that seems normal. Probably you want to always increase K in both cases of the skip.

```
var b :boolean

while not eof(df) do
    begin
        readln(df,s);
        b:=true;
        for j:=1 to length(s) do   
          if s[j]=' ' then b:=false;
        if b then
           writeln(s);  
    end;
```

would do the same. You can remove the whole loop in most compiles with

```
  if Pos(' ',s)=0 then 
     writeln(s)
```

even.